# What happens when I write `char str[80];`?

Tags: c, arrays, string, memory

What happens behind the scenes when I write: `char str[80];`?

I notice that I can now set `str = "hello";` and also `str = "hello world";` right afterwards. First time `strlen(str)` is `5`, and second time it is `11`;

But why? I thought that after `str = "hello";`, the char at index 5 becomes null (`str[5]` becomes `'\0'`). Doesn't that mean that `str`'s size is now 6 and I shouldn't be able to set it to `"hello world"`?

And if not, then how does `strlen` and `sizeof` calculate the correct values every time?

Comment: `strlen` does not include the null-character. And in any case, writing data into the `str` array, does not affect the size to which you have declared this array (80).

Comment: Yes you did: "Doesn't that mean that `str`'s size is now 6?".

Comment: I meant size, not length

Comment: "how does `strlen` and `sizeof` calculate the correct values every time?" - `strlen` searches for the null-character **during runtime**. `sizeof` is replaced (by the compiler) **during compile time**.

Comment: When you do `char str[80]` you're allocating space for 80 chars. Even when you do `str = "123"`, there is still space for 80 chars, so you can just reset it to some other string, and `strlen` will count the number of chars up to the null byte.

Comment: Well, to put it short (and as I've already mentioned in the first comment) - writing data into a variable does impact **the size** of that variable. For example: `int x = 5` doesn't change the size of `x` from `sizeof int` to `sizeof char`, although 5 can fit into a `char`.

Comment: You can't do `str = "hello";`. You can't assign to an array.

Comment: @Barmar: The description implies that OP knows this, and has used this notion just in order to simplify the question (i.e., he or she has used `strcpy`). That's just an opinion of course, but I think it's pretty well founded (but then again, that's also an opinion).

Comment: We have to assume that the posted code is what the question is about..  In which case str = "Hello"; results in the address of the literal "Hello" is assigned to the first few bytes of the array str[].  How many bytes of str[] are modified?  The number of bytes in any pointer on the architecture with the given compile parameters.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you're getting confused between two different concepts: the *allocated length* of the array (how much total space is available), and the *logical length* of the string (how much space is being used).

When you write `char str[80]`, you're getting storage space for 80 characters. You might not end up *using* all of that space, but regardless of what string you try storing in it, you're always going to have 80 slots into which you can place characters.

If you store the string `"hello"` into `str`, then the first six characters of `str` will be set to `h`, `e`, `l`, `l`, `o`, and a null terminating character. This doesn't change the *allocated length*, though - you still have 74 other slots that you can work with. If you then change it to `"hello, world"`, you're using an extra seven characters, which fits just fine because you easily have enough *allocated space* to hold things. You've just changed the *logical length*, how much of that space is being used for meaningful data, but not the *allocated length*, how much space there is available.

Think of it this way. When you say `char str[80]`, you're buying a plot of land that's, say, 80 acres. If you then put `"hello"` into it, you're using six acres of that available 80 acres. The rest of the land is still yours - you can build whatever you'd like there - so if you decide to tear everything down and build a longer string that uses up more acres of land, that's fine. No one is going to object.

The `strlen` function gives back the *logical length* of the string - how many characters are in the string that you're storing. It works by counting up characters until it finds a null terminator indicating the *logical* end of the string. The `sizeof` operator returns the *allocated length* of the array, how many slots you have. It works at compile-time and doesn't care what the array contents are.

Comment: actually `strlen()` returns the index value for the terminating NUL char of the string.  Remember that indexs  for arrays in C start with 0 so the value return by `strlen()` is the number of bytes used BEFORE the trailing NUL characters

Comment: @user3629249 Oh, definitely. I was making a distinction between "the number of characters in the logical string being stored" and "the number of characters used to encode that string," though perhaps I didn't do the best job doing so.

Answer (score 1):

When you declare a variable as char str[80], space for an 80 character array is allocated on the stack. This memory will be automatically released when that particular stack frame is out of scope.

When you assign it to the string literal "hello", it is copying each character into the array, then putting a null terminator at the end of the string (str[5] == '\0'). String length and array size are two different things, which is why you can reassign it to "hello world". String length is simply how many consecutive characters there are before the null terminator. If you instead declared str as char str[5], you would indeed cause a crash when you tried to reassign it to "hello world". It may be helpful to view a simple implementation of strlen:

```
size_t strlen(const char *str)
{
    size_t return_val = 0;
    while (str[return_val] != '\0') return_val++;
    return return_val;
}
```

Of course, if there is no null terminating character, the above naive implementation will crash.

Comment: The "naive" implementation is actually how `strlen` is implemented normally - it is undefined behavior to pass a non-null terminated string to it.

Comment: As Govind said, this is one of the unsafe parts of C. It is the programmer's job to ensure strings are terminated properly.

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that you are working in C.  When you compile "char str[80];" basically a 80 character long space is allocated for you.  sizeof(str) should always tell you that it is an 80 byte long chunk of memory.  strlen(str) will count the non-zero characters starting at str[0].  This is why "Hello" is 5 and "Hello world".

I would suggest that you learn to use functions like strnlen, strncpy, strncmp, snprintf ..., this way you can prevent reading/writing beyond the end the array, for example: strnlen(str,sizeof(str)).

Also start working through online tutorials and find an introductory C/C++ book to learn from.

Answer (score 0):

When you declare an array like `char str[80];`  80 `char`s of space are reserved on the stack for you, but they are not initialized - they get whatever was already in memory at the time.  It's your job as the programmer to initialize the array.

`strlen` does something along these lines:

```
int strlen(char *s)
{
     int len = 0;
     while(*s++) len++;
     return len;
}
```

In other words, it returns the length of a null-terminated string *in* a character array, even if the length is less than the size of the total array.

`sizeof` returns the size of a type or expression.  If your array is 80 `char`s long, and a `char` is a byte long, it will return 80, even if none of the values in the array have been initialized.  If you had an array of 5 `int`s, and an `int` was 4 bytes long, `sizeof` would produce 20.